# Whats the function showChrome() for?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit

It seems to be for rendering (updating) something in specific. But what is showChrome()  really for ?

Not sure if this function is available for all browsers, but right now I'm focusing on webkit based browsers (chrome and safari)

Comment: By the way, I don't think that Opera is based on Webkit. It's based on Presto.

Comment: Thats correct, I meant Safari (don't know what I was thinking there), at least I tagged the question with safari